# Handle session in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI version 3 and want to store session data in database. Below is my config details.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

And my session table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`data` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

I am also load session library in autoload, but still data not stored in databse. I am also tried to store in file but nothing to store.

Comment: Did you check, if your database structure was created correctly? In the docs, you have `id varchar(**128**) NOT NULL`. Btw.: I use files driver with setting `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'ci_sessions/';` Also, if you are not using CI 3.1.11, consider upgrading, as there were problems with sessions reported in earlier 3.x versions

Comment: No, I am upgrade ci version and also i am changed sess save path, But still it not store in db or files.